# 'resources not defined in androidjs

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, web-applications, node-modules

I am very new to androidjs.
I tried to build my project but it shows that resource is undefined. I would like to know how I can move forward with it. I have attached my cmd photo.
I installed androidjs 2.0.3 good internet also have java SDK 1.8
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uUZQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot suggests there is an error on line 41 of update_theme.js. Please, can you post the update_theme.js code.